# knife search returns stale data until chef-client runs. Is this avoidable?

Tags: chef-infra, knife

Example: devjmxpx03/4 are preexisting nodes with the `jmx-proxy-service-tmbveg1` role applied to them.  After applying the role to a new node (`devjmxpx05`), the new node is not immediately available in searches.

```
[~/chef/roles/jmx-proxy-service]$ knife search roles:jmx-proxy-service-tmbveg1 -i
2 items found

devjmxpx03
devjmxpx04
```

Once chef-client runs on `devjmxpx05`, it shows up in searches as expected.

Is there any way around this behavior so that the node will show up in role searches as soon as the role is applied?  Perhaps some additional search parameters?

We are running Chef server v 11.0.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is difference between `role` and `roles` when doing searches. It's described in [search documentation](https://docs.chef.io/chef_search.html#roles-in-run-lists). Just keep in mind using `roles` will look in expanded run_list, `role` won't (it's described in doc as well).

So you probably want to use `role` if it's in top level run list. I think it worked the same in 11.x.

Comment: The search use the solr index on node attribute, which won't be updated unless the run has completed IIRC.

Comment: The [11.0 doc](https://docs.chef.io/release/11-0/chef_search.html#roles-in-run-lists) say the same, so it should work if it's a top level role (within a few min after update, time for the change to be indexed)